# Determine Orientation of a Sketched Arrow with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I've got a bunch of arrow sketches and I want to determine their orientation, the starting point coordinates, and the ending point coordinates.

I'm using `goodFeaturesToTrack` but I'm really clueless as to what to do next.

This is what I've got

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

There is no restriction on the shape of the arrows, they can be as windy as you want them or they could be composed of straight lines and right angles.

I'd really appreciate any ideas because I really am lost. The project is about transforming a sketch of an Finite State Machine into a VHDL code and I've got the circles and characters covered so this is the last component but I have no idea how to approach the problem.

Comment: I'd try a Canny edge detector. But your question is too broad for SO, imo.

Comment: Could you explain a little more, I'm not sure how `Canny` helps, it is a pre-step for `goodFeaturesToTrack`. Yeh, I agree it is broad, but it's because I've exhausted all my ideas, I was kind of desperately hoping someone who already solved this problem would see the question. Besides, I don't need a complete solution, just a new suggestion I could try.

Comment: I guess look for the arrow tips -- as for how, I don't really have much clue at this moment (and i'm a bit tipsy too :D ) The arrow tip looks like a place where 3 lines fitted to nearby points almost intersect. I know it's rather vague, but it may be useful observation.

Comment: Did you figure out the best approach to get the desired result, I used hough lines but I only get one single line and not even a line segment, if I found a line segment then i at least find the start and endpoints, then I can define the position of the pointer(arrow). If you figured it out that how to solve this please upload your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `goodFeaturesToTrack` you can use `HoughLines` which will give you all lines in an image so I suggest that you do some segmentation first to get each arrow separately. `HoughLines` gives you all lines in polar coordinates which is perfect for you case as you can know the orientation of the lines. You can read more here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html

For straight lines your task is easy you need to find 3 line segments that intersect in one point (http://answers.opencv.org/question/92164/how-to-find-coordinates-of-intersection-of-lines-after-using-houghlines/). This will be the end point of your arrow, you can find the start point using the equation of the middle line.

For curved lines, it is a bit more tricky as you may get several hough lines for the curved segment or none at all. So in this case I suggest you get the intersection of the the 2 lines as your end point and then use `goodFeaturesToTrack` then starting from the closest point to your end point start moving to the next closer until you reach the end and pick that as the starting point.

I do not know if this would be the best solution and I did not try it myself but I hope it helps you or give you some direction.

Comment: Thank you very much, definitely improved the accuracy although still not perfect. Sometimes not even the lines at the arrowhead are being detected, although maybe playing around with parameters a bit more may work.

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad I could help. I suggest you do some segmentation before you try to detect the arrows. Hope that helps.